# How to smooth scroll to page anchor in angular 4 without plugins properly?

Tags: angular, typescript, scroll, routes

What I want to achieve is a click to  and do a smooth scroll to bottom / specified div area which i define with hashtag just like  i think it should be like this.

here is the live example in the w3school example which is written for JQuery: https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/tryit.asp?filename=tryjquery_eff_animate_smoothscroll

What I do is peek from this answer: [Angular2 Routing with Hashtag to page anchor](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36101756/angular2-routing-with-hashtag-to-page-anchor)

but i don't really understand the answer, the answer is looked like this :

this part is HTML part :

```
<a [routerLink]="['somepath']" fragment="Test">Jump to 'Test' anchor </a>
```

and below this, the router.navigate is where should I put the code? component.ts right? but how do i access this function? should i implement (click)?

```
this._router.navigate( ['/somepath', id ], {fragment: 'test'});
```

and below this, i get it, which it should write in my component.ts :

```
** Add Below code to your component to scroll**

  import {ActivatedRoute} from '@angular/router'; // <-- do not forget to import

  private fragment: string;

  constructor(private route: ActivatedRoute { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.route.fragment.subscribe(fragment => { this.fragment = fragment; });
  }

  ngAfterViewInit(): void {
    try {
      document.querySelector('#' + this.fragment).scrollIntoView();
    } catch (e) { }
  }
```

what is the "somepath" mean? I should add a route in my routes.ts right? usually, i add a new path in here for example like this :

```
export const routes: Routes = [
  { path: '', redirectTo: '/home', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'product', redirectTo: '/product' },
  ...homeRoutes,
  ...productRoutes
];
```

can anyone provide me with full example code in HTML, routes, and component?

Comment: from what i read and what i search, it will be a hell of a code for just a SMOOTH SCROLL its not simply like JQuery i think, so i decided to use this plugins which is work perfectly : https://www.npmjs.com/package/@nicky-lenaers/ngx-scroll-to feel free to use it

Answer (score 125, accepted):

I was looking for a similar solution and tried to use the [ngx-scroll-to](https://www.npmjs.com/package/@nicky-lenaers/ngx-scroll-to) package and found that its not working in latest version of angular (angular 6+) so decided to look into other option and found a solution which uses the browser's [native](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView)  `scrollIntoView` and this seems to be the best solution so far

HTML code :

```
<button (click)="scrollToElement(target)"></button>
<div #target>Your target</div>
```

Ts code :

```
scrollToElement($element): void {
    console.log($element);
    $element.scrollIntoView({behavior: "smooth", block: "start", inline: "nearest"});
  }
```

Comment: Super! Right now the best solution. You would also need a Polyfill in order support more browsers: https://github.com/iamdustan/smoothscroll

Comment: It seems to me that this, with the polyfill, is the correct answer.

Comment: A simple and "native" solution that doesn't require an external library seems to be the best one

Comment: Note that unfortunately this doesn't work on iOS Safari - seems that `scrollIntoViewOptions` isn't supported at all.

Comment: *IMPORTANT* now Nicky Lenaers ngx-scroll-to supports Angular 8!

Comment: how can we combine `scrollIntoView` function with a fixed header?

Comment: It's not obvious from your example what are you passing in `target` variable to `scrollToElement()` function. Can you please explain?

Comment: It should be noted that this solution (and all the other solutions except for the CSS one which is not widely supported), will not update the router and browser URL history. This means there's no back/forward navigation, and scroll to fragment using URL functionality.

Answer (score 43):

## CSS only solution

```
html {
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}
```

It works even after navigation or page reload.

**Please note that it does not work in IE, Edge or Safari.**

Comment: This can break a lot of stuff. We had to disable it because of a 3rd party modal no longer working property (due to auto-focus). Be very very careful

Answer (score 25):

You can simply do this in your component.

```
const element = document.querySelector("#destination")
if (element) element.scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'smooth', block: 'start' })
```

Ref: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/scrollIntoView

Comment: Didn't work for me but when I switched the first line in the above code example to: const element = document.getElementById("#destination"); then it worked.

Answer (score 8):

In new Angular versions the solution is:

**component.html**

```
<p (click)="scrollTo()">scroll</p>
   .
   .
   .
<form id="myForm">
   .
   .
   .
</form>
```

**component.ts**

```
constructor(private viewportScroller: ViewportScroller) {}

scrollTo() {
    this.viewportScroller.scrollToAnchor('myForm');
}
```

**your-general-styles.css**

```
html {
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}
```

Comment: This should be the accepted answer...Elegant solution in my opinion..Thanks

Comment: Does nothing for me. Don't know why. Trying to scroll to the top of div. Angular 13.

Answer (score 5):

```
 // you can use ViewportScroller calss
 constructor(
        private viewPortscroller: ViewportScroller
        ) {}

scrollingTop() {
    this.viewPortscroller.scrollToPosition([0 , 0]);
  }

// and for smoothly scroll you can do that

html, body {
     height: 100%;
     scroll-behavior: smooth;
 }
```

Answer (score 5):

you have to add the flowing:

**1-** in `app-routing.module.ts` :

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes,
      {
        useHash: true,
        scrollPositionRestoration: 'top',
        anchorScrolling: 'enabled',
        scrollOffset: [0, 64],
        relativeLinkResolution: 'legacy'
      }
    )],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
export class AppRoutingModule { }
```

**2-** in `style.scss` :

```
body, html {
  overflow-x: hidden;
  scroll-behavior: smooth !important;
}
```

**3-** in the `.html` file :

```
<li>
    <a routerLink="home">Home</a>
</li>
<li>
    <a routerLink="." fragment="about">About</a>
</li>
```

OR like this:

```
<div class="mt-4">
      <a class="main-button" style="margin-left: 0px;" routerLink="." fragment="testimonials">
           testimonials
       </a>
</div>
```

Comment: Just to add on to this for those wondering, you also need to give your element an `id` of whatever the `fragment` name is.  In this example, `about` is the fragment, so the about section (anchor) needs to have `id="about"`

Answer (score 3):

I just used [ngx-page-scroll](https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-page-scroll). It can be as simple as:

```
<a class="nav-link nav-item-text" pageScroll href="#categories">Categorias</a>

....

<section id="categories">
```

Visit the package page for more information: https://www.npmjs.com/package/ngx-page-scroll

It also provides mechanisms to configure scrolling process, or event implement custom behavior through a service that controls the scrolling from the component's controller.

Answer (score 2):

You can do it with the help of `ViewportScroller` which defines a scroll position manager.
First of all, you have to inject it in the constructor like the following:

```
import { ViewportScroller } from '@angular/common';
...
constructor(
   ...
   private readonly _viewportScroller: ViewportScroller){}
...
```

Then

```
this._viewportScroller.scrollToPosition([0, 0])
```

### NOTE

Add this style to your  **CSS**  or  **SCSS**  file to add a smooth scroll effect in your app.

```
html {
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}
```

### Methods

**ScrollToPosition**

> ```
> /**
>  * Scrolls to a specified position.
>  * @param position A position in screen coordinates (a tuple with x and y values).
>  */
> abstract scrollToPosition(position: [number, number]): void;
> ```

**ScrollToAnchor**

> ```
> /**
>  * Scrolls to an anchor element.
>  * @param anchor The ID of the anchor element.
>  */
> abstract scrollToAnchor(anchor: string): void;
> ```

**setOffset**

**getScrollPosition**

**setHistoryScrollRestoration**

**[For More Information](https://angular.io/api/common/ViewportScroller)**

Answer (score 1):

Try removing the square brackets:

```
class="startScroll" scrollTo="'#firstDiv'" scrollBoxID="'#scrollBox'"
```

Comment: I have tried with removed and getting this error: `ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'top' of undefined`

Answer (score 1):

I got it work by doing this, consider that top-page is the id that you want to scroll to.

```
document.getElementById("top-page").scrollTo({ behavior: "smooth", top: 0 });
```

Answer (score 1):

you could use css with this :

```css
html {
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

document.getElementById("top-page").scrollIntoView({ behavior: "smooth" });

Answer (score 0):

Add the below lines in style.css to get nicescroll in your angular application page.

```
::-webkit-scrollbar {
    width: 5px;
}


::-webkit-scrollbar-thumb {
    border-radius: 10px;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 6px rgba(0,0,0,0.5); 
    background: #c3c3c3 !important;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the native feature for anchor-based scrolling in angular.
Please refer to this [link](https://medium.com/@navyjot/smooth-scroll-in-angular-c3e9942d23a1) for more info.

Answer (score -1):

```
constructor(private el: ElementRef)

ngAfterViewInit() {
  setTimeout(() => {
    this.el.nativeElement.scrollIntoView({
      behavior: 'smooth',
      block: 'center',
    });
  }, 0);
}
```