# Angular 7 scroll to dynamic ngb-tab from child of a sibling component

Tags: angular, scroll

I have the following structure:

```
<component overview>
  <child component item-info>
<component details>
```

In the child component item-info I have some information about the item. In component details I have all items dynamically listed (ngb-tab - can be closed tab) where I can edit them. I would like to have a link on each item-info in the child component and if I click on this link, it should be scrolled to the tab inside the component details.

I have tried to use the module "ngx-scroll-to":

The button would be in the "child component item-info":

```
<button [ngx-scroll-to]="'#destination'">Go to destination</button>
```

And this div would be in "component details":

```
<div id="destination" #destinationRef>
  You've reached your destination.
</div>
```

I have also tried the approach with "scrollIntoView":

The button would be in the "child component item-info":

```
<button (click)="scroll(target)">
  Scroll to details
</button>
public scroll(id: any) {
    document.getElementById(id)
    element.scrollIntoView();
}
```

And this div would be in "component details":

Unfortunately both approaches did not work. As I understood correctly the second approach doesn't work because scrollIntoView and the element reside in different templates (components). I need a way how could I access to the html of the sibling component to a child of a sibling component.

I was thinking to create a dynamic [id] to the details and pass them somehow to the child component but at the moment I'm at a loss how to solve this problem.

**EDIT**: 
Thanks to **@JoelJoseph** this is working:
The second approach is working!
I would appreciate any help! The problem I have now is that the tabs are dynamically populated with ngfor and the ngfor is only if you open the tab. However, if you collapse the tab again also the rendered details disappear!
Is it somehow possible to force the ngfor run and leave the html rendered even though the tab is collapsed?

Thanks

John

Comment: you can make the second method work by just passing the id instead of reference 
 as you mentioned and use `let element = document.getElementById('put id here');` make sure  the div has id . and then  `element.scrollIntoView({behavior: "smooth", block: "start", inline: "nearest"});`

Comment: check out this article https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46658522/how-to-smooth-scroll-to-page-anchor-in-angular-4-without-plugins-properly/51400379#51400379  hope it helps

Comment: Hi @JoelJoseph, thanks a lot, that worked! :) The last issue I'm facing is that the details are in a ngb-tab and if its collapsed, the id cannot be found. So if I would click to the link, it should be scrolled the tab and the tab should be opened. Do you have a hint for this? Thanks!!