# Scrolltop not working inside a angular material tab

Tags: angular, html, angular-material

I am trying to apply scroll top for the content inside mat tab. It is not happening. I am new to this. Any help is much appreciated

I tried using  a div as well

```css
css:
height:300px;
overflow:auto;
```

```html
<mat-tab>

 <div  #tab [scrollTop]="tab.scrollHeight">
 Content
 </div>

</mat-tab>
```

Comment: Please add code sample or working example in stackblitz

Comment: check this article : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46658522/how-to-smooth-scroll-to-page-anchor-in-angular-4-without-plugins-properly/51400379#51400379

Comment: i added snippet to the question