# How to smooth scroll up on page - Angular 7

Tags: angular, scroll, smooth-scrolling, js-scrollintoview

It's supposed to be simple, but since yesterday i'm trying to smooth scroll up on the page. 
The scroll function works, but not the smooth scrolling.

I tryed : `scrollIntoView({behavior: 'smooth'})` , but it doesn't work.

This is my html component

```
        <div *ngIf="displayNoneOnBtn" [hidden]="!displayNoneOnBtn"  id="btnTest" class="shadow d-flex flex-column align-items-center justify-content-center">
            <ng-container *ngIf="!disableBtn">
                <i class="material-icons arrow-up-button" (click)="scrollTopWindow()">keyboard_arrow_up</i>
            </ng-container>
            <ng-container *ngIf="disableBtn">
                <i class="material-icons arrow-down-button" (click)="scrollDown()">keyboard_arrow_down</i>
            </ng-container>
        </div>
```

And my TS component

```
    import {Component, OnInit, ElementRef} from '@angular/core';
import 'hammerjs';
import { SessionService, UiService } from 'src/app/core/services';

@Component({
    templateUrl: './frontend.component.html',
    styleUrls: ['./frontend.component.scss'],
})

export class FrontendComponent implements OnInit {
    top: number;
    disableBtn = true;
    scrollHeight: number;
    displayNoneOnBtn = true;

    constructor(
        public sessionService: SessionService,
        public uiService: UiService,
        private el: ElementRef,
    ) {
    }

    scrollClass: any;

    ngOnInit(): void {
        this.scrollClass = Array.prototype.slice.call(this.el.nativeElement.getElementsByClassName('pageScroll'), 0)[0];
        console.log('scroll scrollTop', this.scrollClass.scrollTop);
        console.log('scroll scrollHeight', this.scrollClass.scrollHeight);
        console.log('scroll offsetHeight', this.scrollClass.offsetHeight);
    }

    asideNavToogle(status: string) {
        this.uiService.stateAsideNav = status;
    }

    scrollDown() {
        this.scrollClass.scrollTop = this.scrollClass.scrollHeight;
    }

    scrollTopWindow() {
        this.scrollClass.scrollTop = 0;
        this.el.nativeElement.scrollIntoView({behavior: 'smooth'});
    }

    onScroll (event: Event) {
        console.log('scroll scrollTop', this.scrollClass.scrollTop);
        console.log('scroll scrollHeight', this.scrollClass.scrollHeight);
        console.log('scroll offsetHeight', this.scrollClass.offsetHeight);
        if (this.scrollClass.scrollTop === 0) {
            this.disableBtn = true;
        }
        if (this.scrollClass.scrollHeight === this.scrollClass.scrollTop + this.scrollClass.offsetHeight) {
            this.disableBtn = false;
        }
        if (this.scrollClass.scrollHeight === this.scrollClass.offsetHeight) {
            this.displayNoneOnBtn = false ;
        }

    }

}
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46658522/how-to-smooth-scroll-to-page-anchor-in-angular-4-without-plugins-properly/75210400#75210400

Answer (score 7):

I did the example below:

https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-vjsz9w

I hope I've helped.

Answer (score -6):

I solved the problem by using a Jquery function :

```
    scrollDown() {
        $('.pageScroll').animate({
            scrollTop: this.scrollClass.scrollHeight
        }, 500);
    }

    scrollTop() {
        $('.pageScroll').animate({
            scrollTop: 0
        }, 500);
    }
```

Comment: Please do not use Jquery in angular applications. Its not a safe and not recommended approach for angular 2+ applications.