# Angular: scrollIntoView on Component

Tags: angular, typescript

I've this subcomponent reference using `@ViewChild` anotation:

```
@ViewChild(UserSubComponent)
private userManagementComponent: UserSubComponent;
```

I'd like to use this reference to perform `scrollIntoView`.

Is it possible?

Comment: you may use  the method use in this answer : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46658522/how-to-smooth-scroll-to-page-anchor-in-angular-4-without-plugins-properly/51400379#51400379

Comment: Or use [fragments](https://angular.io/guide/router#query-parameters-and-fragments) the Angular way of doing so

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change your selector so that it returns an ElementRef.

```
@ViewChild(UserSubComponent, {read: ElementRef})
private userManagementComponent: ElementRef;
```

then use the native element to scroll into view when you want:

```
ngOnInit(){
  this.userManagementComponent.nativeElement.scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'smooth', block: 'start' });
}
```