# window.scroll doesn't scroll accurately

Tags: javascript, css, angular

I have sticky header when page is scrolled it is fixed at the top of the page.when I click on the menu in the header page must scroll to that particular div.For sticky header i am using angular.for scrolling normal java script window.scroll(). but window.scroll() not scrolling accurately.

//stickyheader.html

```
<div #stickyMenu [class.sticky]="sticky">
  <div class="header">

    <div class="navbar">
      <ul>
        <li><a>Home</a></li>

        <li><a (click)="scrollTo('candidate')">Candidate</a></li>
        <li><a (click)="scrollTo('client')">Client</a></li>
        <li><a (click)="scrollTo('user')">User</a></li>
      </ul>
    </div>


  </div>
</div>
```

//stickyhedaer.ts

```
import { Component, OnInit, AfterViewInit, ViewChild, ElementRef, HostListener } from '@angular/core';
import { TargetLocator } from 'selenium-webdriver';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-sticky-header',
  templateUrl: './sticky-header.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./sticky-header.component.css']
})
export class StickyHeaderComponent implements OnInit, AfterViewInit                 {

  @ViewChild('stickyMenu') menuElement: ElementRef;

  sticky: boolean;
  elementPosition: any;
  myElement: ElementRef;
  constructor() {
    this.sticky = false;
  }

  ngAfterViewInit() {
   this.elementPosition = this.menuElement.nativeElement.offsetTop;
    console.log(this.menuElement);
  }

  @HostListener('window:scroll', ['$event'])
  handleScroll() {
    const windowScroll = window.pageYOffset;
   if (windowScroll >= this.elementPosition) {
      this.sticky = true;
      console.log(this.elementPosition + ' host listener scroll');
    } else {
      this.sticky = false;
    }
  }
  scrollTo(id: any) {
    console.log(id);
    id = document.getElementById(id);

    // id.scrollIntoView({ behavior: 'smooth', block: 'nearest', inline: 'start' });

    const yCoordinate = id.getBoundingClientRect().top + window.pageYOffset;
    const yOffset = 70;
    window.scroll({
      top: yCoordinate - yOffset,
      behavior: 'smooth'
    });
}
}
```

//app.component.html

```
<div>

  <div class="content"></div>
  <app-sticky-header></app-sticky-header>
  <app-candidate></app-candidate>
  <app-client></app-client>     
  <app-user></app-user>
  <div class="content"></div>

</div>
```

Comment: scroll to a particular div can be achieved like this : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46658522/how-to-smooth-scroll-to-page-anchor-in-angular-4-without-plugins-properly/51400379#51400379

Comment: also here is a sample for sticky header on scroll : http://joeljoseph.net/angular-sticky-header-on-scroll/

Comment: @JoelJoseph  I tried scrollIntoView(),same issue section scrolls to top of the page  and overlaps with sticky header by hiding sections top element

Answer (score 1):

I made a stackblitz example related to your query. In that header sticky and scrolling to that section is working properly. I didn't add multiple compnent. Instead of that i added text in

tag and gave same id to that section.

[Working Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-uqvqjm?file=src/app/stickyheader/stickyheader.component.html)

Comment: Replaced Text with component ,it works fine there but here doesn't work

Comment: i updated the abouve stackblitz by replacing text with different components. Please check and let me know for further issue