# Angular - Scroll to the bottom of an element

Tags: html, angular

So I have this 'output' element which fills up with messages, the overflow is set on `scroll` so after a certain amount of messages this element becomes scrollable. It doesn't auto scroll to the bottom though, so I tried doing this using the DOM, `document.getElementById('output')`, this didn't work and after some reading I learned this should be avoided in angular.

So I want to target this `#output` element in my `output-window` component with my typescript and access some `scrollTo()` method to scroll it to the bottom, how should I do this?

**output-window.component.html:**

```
<div id="output">
  <p *ngFor="let message of messages">
    {{ message }}
  </p>
</div>
```

**Project structure**

```
home.component
+-->output-window.component
    +-->div#output
```

Targeting this `div#output` is what's giving me trouble.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46658522/how-to-smooth-scroll-to-page-anchor-in-angular-4-without-plugins-properly/51400379#51400379

Answer (score 0, accepted):

retrieve p tags with view children

```
 @ViewChildren("p") ps: QueryList<any>
 ngAfterViewInit() {
    this.ps.last.nativeElement.scrollIntoView();
  }
```

then access to native element and then scroll to it.
or better approach is write a directive for p element and set it for last element

Edit : It seems you need to name your p element like below

```
   <div id="output">
    <p *ngFor="let message of messages" #p>
       {{ message }}
     </p>
   </div>
```

in order to make ViewChildren work properly.

Comment: Your edit seems to have fixed it :) And with that fix my problem is solved!

Answer (score 0):

I have created a stack blitz for you. Please check [here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-e3i7ri)