# angular smooth scroll when add fix class

Tags: css, angular

when first scroll done my header get fix position but my challenge is => scroll is not smooth and change suddenly position

```
.sticky-part {
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 9999;
  width: 100%;
  background-color: white;
  height: 95px;
}


  scroll = (): void => {
if (window.scrollY == 0) {
  this.isScroll = false;
}
else {
  this.isScroll = true;
}
```

};

```
<div class="header-container" [class.sticky-part]="(showMessageBox | async) && !isHome && isScroll"></div>
```

Comment: maybe this will help you  : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46658522/how-to-smooth-scroll-to-page-anchor-in-angular-4-without-plugins-properly/51400379#51400379

Comment: also please check this article : http://joeljoseph.net/angular-sticky-header-on-scroll/