# scrollIntoView to anchor in different components

Tags: angular, scroll, angular8, js-scrollintoview

I have an Angular 8 SPA with a fixed-top navbar to auto-scroll the user to the section he clicked.

[image]

In the first place, I used a simple `href="#section1"`. When the user clicks on a link in the navbar, the associated section is displayed properly. But I wanted to make it smooth, so I decided to use the `scrollIntoView` method instead as shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46658522/how-to-smooth-scroll-to-page-anchor-in-angular-4-without-plugins-properly).

Unfortunately, it doesn't seem to work. The method `scrollToElement()` is in the `navbar component` and the target section is in another component (for the moment, the `app component`, but this will change in future...). Because the anchor is in another component, when I click `<a>`, the element is undefined and I get this error in the console : `ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'scrollIntoView' of undefined`

**`app.component.html`**

```
...
<div #section1></div>
<div #section2></div>
<div #section3></div>
<div #section4></div>
...
```

**`navbar.component.html`**

```
... 
<li class="nav-item">
  <a (click)="scrollToElement(section1)" class="nav-link">Section1</a>
</li>
...
```

**`navbar.component.ts`**

```
...
scrollToElement($element: any): void {
    console.log($element); //returns undefinded
    $element.scrollIntoView({ //throws an error because $element is undefined
      behavior: "smooth",
      block: "start",
      inline: "nearest"
    });
  }
...
```

I think I am getting the problem, but I don't understand how to solve it. Should I use a variable in the `navbar.component.ts` to store the element before using the `scrollIntoView` method ?

Thanks in advance for your help!

**SOLVED**

**`navbar.component.html`**

```
... 
<li class="nav-item">
  <a (click)="scrollToElement('#section1')" class="nav-link">Section1</a>
</li>
...
```

**`navbar.component.ts`**

```
...
  scrollToElement(selector) {
    const element = document.querySelector(selector)
    element ? element.scrollIntoView({behavior: "smooth"}): null;
  }
...
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you are accessing your variable reference on other component

You are declaring your variable on **app.component.html** and
You are trying to access those variables from **navbar.component.html** that not works in angular.