# Angular_show the view on the top

Tags: typescript

Here is the question,
I have a click button.this click event will upadate angular view,Then I want to let the view will show on the top but not using ScrollToTop, So what method can i use?

Having soultions for mine problem

Comment: You can use [ViewPortScroller](https://angular.io/api/common/ViewportScroller)

Comment: I  use it . but it scoll smoothly, is there have any way to scroll immediately?

Comment: Try `window` as parameter, `this.viewportScroller.scrollToTop(window);`

Comment: I find the solution at https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69585152/angular-scrollpositionrestoration-without-animation-smooth-scrolling, but also thanks for your answer!